# Jingle (XEP-0166): Does any Multimedia Data go via my server, and if not, who is billed for the data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, xmpp, p2p, out-of-band

I am running an Openfire server on a AWS EC2 instance and am able to connect to the server from my mobile devices and send messages back and forth. Of course, since XMPP is a client-server based protocol, I incur costs for running this traffic over the AWS server. However, for most use cases, this cost is not very high at all, as normal XMPP stanzas rarely seem to go above ca. 1 KB, so from this end all is ok.

I would now, however, like to include the ability to send images from one client to another. One way would be to use an HTTP server, to which user A uploads the picture and then sends the URL of the image to user B via XMPP, so that the user can now get the image via HTTP. There are also several other methods for sending images via XMPP. However, I am interested in doing this via Jingle.

As far as as I understand, Jingle is an out of band peer-to-peer extension to XMPP. My simple question is, since Jingle communicates peer-to-peer, i.e. without the use of a server, for the multimedia aspect of the session, will I even incur any data cost on AWS for transferring multimedia from one client to another using Jingle? Or put differently, if Jingle is peer-to-peer, does any data go via my AWS server using Jingle (except the session initiate, ack, session terminate stanzas)? If not, what kind of route does this data take, and how can anyone be billed for this traffic cost, if it is peer-to-peer?

Answer (score 2):

Jingle is a negotiation mechanism, and there are a couple of different transports it could negotiate for file transfer. The most common transport is peer to peer bytestreams defined in http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0260.html - here the only traffic you'd see via the server would be the jingle negotiation, which is a similar sort of volume to other XMPP traffic). There is also an in-band bytestream transport defined in http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0261.html that some clients will use - typically for smaller transfers as it's inefficient, but has the advantage of working in hostile networks with NAT and firewalls. If you control the clients, simply not supporting IBB would be your best bet for ensuring the traffic doesn't travel via the server. If you don't, I'd suggest configuring your server to block IBB traffic.

I note as well that running a server-side proxy will drastically increase the odds of the out-of-band mechanism in 260 working in the face of hostile networks, at the cost of server bandwidth.

There is also the not-widely-deployed http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0343.html out of band transport.

Comment: Thanks for your answer kev. So, say I have a total transfer for images of 20MB per month per user, at 100k users, I have 2TB of traffic per month then. But, if I use Jingle, I would save most of that traffic (except the negotiation cost), and not incur the ca. 2TB at another place, since the image data is going via a p2p transfer? If I understand this correct, this could save us a lot of money in the long run, using p2p for big data transfer.  Thanks again! Chris

Comment: This is true if 
 a) you're using an out of band transport
 b) you're not supplying a server-side proxy to aid with connectivity
yes.